# Racket hollow rectangle

Tags: functional-programming, racket

I'm kind of curious how to write a Code that displays a hollow rectangle in Dr.Racket. I really don't have any clue, because I just started practicing some Racket. Hope someone can give some hints.

Comment: What do you call a hollow rectangle ?

Comment: A rectangle made of stars, like in this one: 
******
*      *
*      *
******

Answer (score 0):

One way to repeat something is to use a for-loop.

```
(for ([i 5])
  (display "*"))
(newline)
```

will display five stars followed by a new line.
You can use this to make the top and bottom of your rectangle.

```
(for ([i 5])
  (displayln "*      *"))
```

Will display the string  "*      *" times and change line after each.
You can use that to make the sides of the rectangle.